# My python is poor, I can't find the error in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why will get a empty list for this code? I can't comprehend.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        results = []
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i + j == target and nums.index(i) != nums.index(j):
                    a = nums.index(i)
                    results.append(a)
                    b = nums.index(j)
                    results.append(b)
        return results

h = Solution()
result = h.twoSum([3, 3], 6)
print(result)
```

The result is a empty list.

Comment: Post your code as text, not as a link to an image of text.

Comment: Images of code are not appropriate here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should not use them. You write your code with a text editor using your keyboard, not a graphics editor. Copy and paste the text directly. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], in order to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Perhaps we can be more nice to new contributors.

Comment: Hi Lin,
What is it that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question makes me to memorize my beginner days.You almost there,Try this buddy

```
    class Solution:

    def twoSum(self,nums, target): 
        results = [] 
        for i,val1 in enumerate(nums): 
            for j,val2 in enumerate(nums): 
                if val1+val2 == target and i != j: 
                   results.append([i,j]) 
        return results
    h = Solution()
    result = h.twoSum([3, 3, 2, 4], 6)
    print result

    Result:[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3], [3, 2]]
```

your if condition nums.index(i) != nums.index(j) isn't work,try enumerate for indexing